# How can I add attributes and elements from a new namepace in Wix and ignored by Wix?

Tags: wix, wix3

I want to add a unrelated attribute in the Wix wxs file and want Wix to ignore it.

It currently throws up following error as it goes looking for the extension.

**The Component element contains an unhandled extension attribute 'myns:myattr'.  Please ensure that the extension for attributes in the 'http://tempuri.org/myschema.xsd' namespace has been provided.**

Rob, Bob or anybody on wix team listening!!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Write a wix extension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/extension_development.htm) which handles elements in that XML namespace. The following example extension will cause any elements in the namespace `http://www.example.com` to be ignored:

Save the following code in `mywixext.cs`:

```
using System.Xml.Schema;
using Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml;
using System.Xml;

[assembly: AssemblyDefaultWixExtension(
   typeof(mywixext.IgnoreNamespaceWixExtension))]

namespace mywixext
{

   public class IgnoreNamespaceWixExtension : WixExtension
   {
      public override CompilerExtension CompilerExtension
      {
         get
         {
            return new IgnoreNamespaceCompilerExtension();
         }
      }
   }

   public class IgnoreNamespaceCompilerExtension : CompilerExtension
   {
      public override XmlSchema Schema
      {
         get
         {
            return new XmlSchema() 
            {
               TargetNamespace = "http://www.example.com" 
            };
         }
      }

      public override void ParseElement(
         SourceLineNumberCollection sourceLineNumbers,
         XmlElement parentElement, XmlElement element,
         params string[] contextValues)
      {
         // do nothing
      }

   }
}
```

Now compile it into `mywixext.dll` like this:

```
"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe" /t:library ^
/r:"c:\program files\windows installer xml v3\bin\wix.dll" ^
mywixext.cs
```

If you now compile your wix sources with the option `-ext mywixext.dll` (or do the equivalent in votive) then all elements in the `http://www.example.com` namespace will be ignored.

**edit**: I was imprecise when I said that any element would be ignored. The WIX XML schema does not allow you to add your own child elements directly under the `WIX` element. Most other elements allow it. Look for the text `<xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax">` in `c:\program files\windows installer xml v3\doc\wix.xsd` to find the extensibility points.

Comment: I had tested with my own child element under `<Package>`. You are probably attempting to add stuff directly under `<Wix>`. I have edited my answer to clarify why this is not allowed.

Comment: Because we cannot add attributes to Wix elements but can add new elements to Wix elements.